# API по сокращению ссылок Vk.cc

Tags: javascript, jquery, vkontakte-api

Кто то подскажет, есть ли API для сокращения ссылок в ВК?
Обыскал весь интернет не могу найти
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

API вроде бы, нет, но, [как пишут](https://vk.com/wall-2158488_372391) в оф. группе Live, есть [расширение под Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vkcc-url-shortener/nnfphhchbmhilfllffingfchjhfaagcg), разобрав которое, вероятно, можно понять, как сделать что-то своё.

Upd. похоже, всё просто. Посмотрите, как работает сама страница vk.cc – из формы идёт POST-запрос, и получается короткая ссылка в ответ!  В упомянутом расширении под Chrome это так реализовано:

```
function loadShort(q,done){
  q=trim(q);
  var cache_url=q.replace(/http:\/\//gi,"").replace(/\//gi,"");
  if(s.get("res_"+cache_url)!=null){
    if(done)done("9654<!>profile.css,page.css,profile.js,page.js<!>3<!>3326<!>0<!>"+s.get("res_"+cache_url));
    return;
  }
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        if(done)done(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open("POST", "http://vk.com/cc", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
  xhr.send("act=shorten&al=1&link="+enc(q));
}
```

Реализовать это в рамках обычной веб-страницы на JS не получится из-за того, что они на другом домене расположены, чем ваша страница. Зато через сервер, сделать вполне просто.

Comment: Спасибо)
Жалко, что не получится))

Comment: Получится: вы можете сделать на сервере скрипт, который будет curl'ом получать короткую ссылку. А JS на вашей странице будет обращаться не к vk.cc, а к скрипту на этом же сервере.

Comment: Та я делаю расширение, где хочу сделать несколько серверов сокращение, а там, как понимаете не как)

Comment: Для расширения как раз можно и без усложнений с CORS! Говорю же – разберите то расширение под Chrome : )

Comment: Ну попробую
Спасибо :)